# UPI link from html

Tags: payment, whatsapp, upi

i'm trying send UPI payment link from whatsapp web link

eg. [https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=91%mob%^&app_absent=1^&text="upi://pay?pa=upiaddress@okhdfcbank&pn=JohnDoe&cu=INR"](https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=91%mob%%5E&app_absent=1%5E&text=%22upi://pay?pa=upiaddress@okhdfcbank&pn=JohnDoe&cu=INR%22)

the above msg is going only up to
"upi://pay?pa=upiaddress@okhdfcbank

what could be the issue

i'm trying send UPI payment link from whatsapp web link

eg. [https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=91%mob%^&app_absent=1^&text="upi://pay?pa=upiaddress@okhdfcbank&pn=JohnDoe&cu=INR"](https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=91%mob%%5E&app_absent=1%5E&text=%22upi://pay?pa=upiaddress@okhdfcbank&pn=JohnDoe&cu=INR%22)

the above msg is going only up to
"upi://pay?pa=upiaddress@okhdfcbank

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the URL encoding. When you include special characters or spaces in a URL, you need to properly encode them.

Try the below url

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=91%mob%^&app_absent=1^&text=upi%3A%2F%2Fpay%3Fpa%3Dupiaddress%40okhdfcbank%26pn%3DJohnDoe%26cu%3DINR
```